# MySQL, C++: Retrieving auto-increment ID

Tags: c++, mysql, database, auto-increment, mysql-connector

I have a table with an auto-incrementing ID.  After inserting a new row, I would like to retrieve the new ID.

I found an article that used the MySQL function [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html). The article says to create a new query and submit it.

I'm using MySQL Connector C++, Windows XP and Vista, and Visual Studio 9.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there an API, for the connector,
   that will fetch the ID out of the
   record?
2. Does the result set, after an
   insert/append, contain the new ID?
3. The `LAST_INSERT_ID` is MySQL
   specific.  Is there an SQL
   *standard* method for obtaining the new ID?

Comment: As you said. You can use a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` query instead of calling the library function.

Comment: @Alexandre Jasmin:  Does the C++ connector have the library function?

Comment: I don't see `mysql_insert_id` used anywhere in the connector source tree. I suppose it wouldn't be too difficult to add support for it if you really want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It doesn't look like it - in the C API, you have mysql_insert_id() for this, but it doesn't appear to be used in the C++ connector, nor does it appear to implement the getGeneratedKeys method from the JDBC API (However, I don't use this connector myself, so I may be missing something obvious...).
2. No, there is no result set from an INSERT.
3. No. [Supposedly, DB2 is the only one](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#mix-identity) that follows what the SQL standard says about auto-generated keys; everyone else does it differently (from both the standard and from each other).